# Flagging as Incomplete is inconclusive

Tags: feature-request, flags

Maybe im missing something here, but was about to flag a question today for being incomplete.. Grossly incomplete.

If its still available it is this one : [Bad question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963000/i-want-to-remove-the-top-shadow/)

When i went to flag said question, I selected 
[image: Should be closed : Incomplete]

That was fine, it had the `Incomplete` tag I was looking for. But then on the next step of that report parameter, it gave me unrelated options :

[image: Bad followup SO!! TSK TSK!]

From this selection I have no clear indication which relates to incompleteness.

Im not sure, but shouldnt the incomplete flag either be removed, or perhaps a clear part #2 in the follow up ?

I have added the second tag to this as feature request as I personally would like to see this "This question is incomplete" option on the follow up modal.

Comment: Did you check the sub-reasons of "Off topic because..."? There's one that asks the poster to provide a MCVE. Otherwise, the "unclear" reason is also fitting - the problem is not clearly described in the question. Furthermore, in general it doesn't matter if the close reason fits 100%, just that bad questions are closed quickly.

Comment: @l4mpi ok so the reason is not that important then, great, but the question is not off topic. Seems redundant then to have a "incomplete" mention at all. Just have an option "Flagging, no reason specified." ?

Comment: At that point, why offer reasons at all? If *"no reason specified"* is available, why would people use anything else? The reasons are there to make you reflect on whether and how the question really is off-topic. In this case, you should have considered what made the question incomplete.

Comment: "the question is not off topic" - of course it is. It fails to ask a clear question, which makes it off topic, even though the subject being asked about is in general on topic for the site. Read the MCVE text, it does apply to incomplete questions - but those are just one of the things being covered by the MCVE close reason, which also fits things like people attempting to dump their whole program and 10k lines of log files without narrowing their problem down to a minimal example. As there are only a limited amount of close reasons, there can't be one for each specific case.

Comment: Fair enough all fair points i guess

Comment: It's *unclear* what you're asking because which one you should have chosen is obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the "incomplete" part often lends itself to selecting "too broad". Most of the questions that I see that are "incomplete" are missing necessary implementation details that make the question specific enough to give a good answer without rewriting a whole textbook chapter.

Selecting Off-Topic -> "Questions seeking debugging help..." is a good choice if the OP left out their expected or observed results, or code necessary to answer the question.